# Im trying to make a 4 columns row in HTML5 but columns showing one under the other instead of side by side

Tags: html, css

I have this lines of code:

```
<section class="section-features">
          <div class="row">
            <h2>HEADER</h2>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col span-1-of-4">
              <h3>HEADER</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col span-1-of-4">
              <h3>HEADER</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

</section>
```

My columns are not showing side by side, instead they are one under the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve this either using [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) or [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and I prefer using Flexbox. I reuse your code and made some tweak, also add comment in the CSS for you to understand what was going on.

```css
.row-flex {
    /* Set display flex on the parent element */    
    display: flex;
    /* Create space between the child items */
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.col {
    /* Column width minus the gutter */
    width: calc(25% - 5%);
    /* Prevent flexbox child item to shrink */
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-features">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>HEADER</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row-flex">
        <div class="col ">
          <h3>HEADER</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <h3>HEADER</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col">
          <h3>HEADER</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col">
          <h3>HEADER</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: css grid did the job! Thanks

Comment: @Javabeginner No worries, some properties might need [some prefix to support IE11](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) (if you want to support it)

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done using display flex property

```css
.row{
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-orientation: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.col{
  -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
  
}
```

Also, this is a great article about how flex works: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

To get them side by side, just add another class to the div that contains the 2 columns, and give that class a display: flex; with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This is as bootstrap grid. If you would search documentations you could find. Link: [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/)

```
<div class=„row”>
<div class=„col-md-3”>1</div>
<div class=„col-md-3”>2</div>
<div class=„col-md-3”>3</div>
<div class=„col-md-3”>4</div>
</div>
```